# Adding existing database date

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a database in Microsoft Access. It turns out that in the meantime I have new fields for my records that are not available for all records.

I was wondering, is there a way to add this information to my table (according to its id of course) using Excel import, without creating a new table? If, yes by what means?

(sorry for my bad English, i'm French)

Answer (score 0):

- Import your new Excel data into a **new** table
- Create a new query where you JOIN the existing table with the imported table
- Change the query to an UPDATE query, and set the empty dates to the ones from the import table.

Something like

```
UPDATE Old INNER JOIN New ON Old.Id = New.Id
SET Old.myDate = New.MyDate
WHERE Old.MyDate Is NULL
```

- run the query
- delete the new table